# ghidra: how to run a python 3 script with headless analyzer

Tags: ghidra

I read the documentation of [headleass analyzer](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/analyzeHeadlessREADME.html#examples). It is used to perform analysis on existing binaries. I know that `-postscript` flag allows to enter the analysis script. I have a java script which works fine. But, I want to use python 3 for the analysis. I want to run that like:

```
./analyzeHeadless ghidra-project-directory -import binary-file -postscript yourpythonscript
```

Is it possible to run python script for the analysis? Also, is there any documentation available to do that?

> Edit:
>
> I made a following script and it does work fine (but it gives me not
>   found errors for DecompInterface):
>
> ```
> import ghidra.app.util.headless.HeadlessScript;
> import ghidra.app.decompiler.ClangNode;
> import ghidra.app.decompiler.ClangToken;
> import ghidra.app.decompiler.ClangLine;
> import ghidra.app.decompiler.ClangTokenGroup;
> import ghidra.app.decompiler.DecompInterface;
> import ghidra.app.decompiler.DecompileResults;
> import ghidra.program.model.address.Address;
> import ghidra.program.model.listing.CodeUnit;
> import ghidra.program.model.listing.Function;
> import ghidra.program.model.listing.FunctionIterator;
> import ghidra.program.model.listing.InstructionIterator;
> import ghidra.program.model.listing.Program;
> import ghidra.program.model.listing.Variable;
> import ghidra.program.model.pcode.HighFunction;
> import ghidra.program.model.pcode.HighSymbol;
> import ghidra.program.model.pcode.HighVariable;
> import ghidra.program.model.pcode.LocalSymbolMap;
> import ghidra.program.model.pcode.PcodeOp;
> import ghidra.program.model.pcode.Varnode;
> import ghidra.program.model.symbol.Symbol;
> import ghidra.program.model.symbol.Reference;
> import ghidra.program.model.symbol.ReferenceIterator;
> import ghidra.util.task.ConsoleTaskMonitor;
>
> args = getScriptArgs()
>
> print(args)
>
> p = currentProgram
> print(p)
>
> filename = "/projects/zephyr/Ruturaj/ghidra_learning/" + p.getName() + ".txt"
> print(filename)
>
> #di = DecompInterface()
> #print(di)
> ```

Comment: AFAIK Ghidra relies on Jython which does not support Python 3. You'll have to use Python 2.

Comment: Thanks @IgorSkochinsky I'll note that down in the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I turns out that the python script can be used with headless analyzer script.

Using the following command I can run it, just like the java file:

```
./analyzeHeadless ghidra-project-directory -import binary-file -postscript yourpythonscript
```

Apparently all the classes defined for java can be used directly in the python script.

Particular class can be imported with `from import statements`, for example in java looks like:

```
import ghidra.program.model.listing.Variable;
```

And using python:

```
from ghidra.program.model.listing import Variable;
```

To import the `variable` class. The variable class can be imported just like java (see the import statement above). But, then you have to use the whole path name to access it. For example:

```
something = ghidra.program.model.listing.Variable()
```

So, in conclusion, the same script can be written using python by importing the classes without any issue. Hope this helps someone.

> Edit:
>
> As @igor said in the comment, it works only with python 2.7 (as ghidra
>   relies on `Jython`). For python 3.x, something like
>   [`ghidra_bridge`](https://github.com/justfoxing/ghidra_bridge) can be
>   used.